# Bad proxy configuration linphone android

Tags: java, android, proxy, voip, linphone

I have just configured linphone sdk for android voip development but i unable to configure registration settings whenever i tries to add LinphoneProxyConfiguration to LinphoneCore it says bad proxy configuration.
logcat throwing an exception saying that bad proxy configuration.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service rana.testculin.TestService: org.linphone.core.LinphoneCoreException: bad proxy config
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2589)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:153)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1374)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5302)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: org.linphone.core.LinphoneCoreException: bad proxy config
            at org.linphone.core.LinphoneCoreImpl.addProxyConfig(LinphoneCoreImpl.java:247)
            at rana.testculin.TestService.<init>(TestService.java:47)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2586)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:153)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1374)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5302)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Java code is

```
  public TestService() throws LinphoneCoreException {
        factory=LinphoneCoreFactory.instance();
        core=factory.createLinphoneCore(this, null);
        address=factory.createLinphoneAddress("sip:<myusernamehere>@sip.linphone.org");
        authInfo=factory.createAuthInfo(address.getUserName(), "an011kit", null, address.getDomain());
        core.addAuthInfo(authInfo);
        proxyConfig=core.createProxyConfig();
        proxyConfig.setProxy(address.getDomain());
        proxyConfig.enableRegister(true);
        core.addProxyConfig(proxyConfig);
```

}
Try to doing this in my constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My code is similar but I use this method

```
core.createProxyConfig(sipAddress, domain, null, true);
```

where sipAddress is "sip:USER@DOMAIN"

EDIT by OP:

```
core.createProxyConfig();
```

doesn't contain required fields to register so we have to pass some parameters that are required to register.
`sipAddress` is used to register you (your IP and Port) on the SIP Server 
`domain` :- any sip domain